# Qt. Передвижение диалога, создание окна and TextExchenged

Tags: qt, окно

- **1 Вопрос**: Я прописал передвижение диалога и в **style** прописал **border** (его цвет и ширину); как сделать так, что бы я мог передвигать только верхнюю полоску и я нажимаю на область этой полоски, у меня мышка не перескакивала, а была на месте, где я её зажал? И еще у меня проблема, при перетаскивание окна(смотря в какую сторону) у меня исчезаю границы, как исправить?
- **2 Вопрос**: Мне нужно окно(не диалог) в котором я могу создать область, в которой я могу рисовать или вставить картинку. Также, как сделать так, что бы я при вносе этого окна в главную область программы они соединялись(что-то вроде AdobePhotoshop)
- **3 Вопрос**: Как проверить, введена ли информация в строку или нет, и если нет, то кнопка не активируется(я пытался искал, но у меня то ли не работает, то ли я плохо написал) и также, как запретить ввод символов и цифри и конечно, как поставить ограничение по количеству букв, которые можна ввести?

P.S. Код касается только диалога!

P.S.2. Как делать тут абзац?

P.S.3. Начинающий программист!

**Заголовочный файл:**

```
namespace Ui {
class newF;
}

class newF : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QPoint previousPosition READ previousPosition WRITE setPreviousPosition NOTIFY previousPositionChanged)

public:
    explicit newF(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~newF();
    QPoint previousPosition() const;

private:
    Ui::newF *ui;

    QPushButton *ok;
    QLineEdit *name;
    QPushButton *cls;
    QPoint m_previousPosition;


protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

public slots:
    void setPreviousPosition(QPoint previousPosition);

signals:
    void previousPositionChanged(QPoint previousPosition);

private slots:
    void cancel(){
        close();
    }
    void exit(){
        close();
    }
    void Ok();
    void TextChanged(const QString text){
        if(!name->text().isEmpty())
        ok->setEnabled (true);
    }

};
```

**Файл реализации:**

```
newF::newF(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::newF)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setModal(true);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    this->setStyleSheet(StyleHelper::getQDialogStyleSheet());

    QPushButton *close = new QPushButton (this);
    close->setGeometry(189, 1, 40, 18);
    close->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                         "image: url(:/images/close.png);"
                         "background-color: #000000;"
                         "border: none;"
                         "}"
                         "QPushButton:hover {"
                         "background-color: red; "
                         "}");
    connect(close,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(exit()));

    QLabel *newf = new QLabel("Name:",this);
    newf->setStyleSheet("QLabel {"
                        "background-color: #363636;"
                        "color: #000000;"
                        "}");
    name = new QLineEdit(this);
    name->text();
    name->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {"
                        "color: #FFFFFF;"
                        "border: 1px double black const;"
                        "};");
    newf->setBuddy(name);
    connect(name, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &text)), this, SLOT(TextChanged(const QString &text)));

    ok = new QPushButton("OK",this);
    ok->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                      "background-color: #696969;"
                      "border: none;"
                      "}");
    ok->setDefault(true);
    ok->setEnabled(false);
    connect(ok,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&newF::Ok);
    QPushButton *cancel = new QPushButton("Cancel",this);
    cancel->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                          "background-color: #696969;"
                          "border: none;"
                          "}"
                          "QPushButton:hover {"
                          "background-color: #7D7D7D;"
                          "}");
    cancel->setGeometry(0, 0, 20, 50);
    connect(cancel,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(cancel()));

    QHBoxLayout *hb1 = new QHBoxLayout;
    hb1->addWidget(newf);
    hb1->addWidget(name);
    QHBoxLayout *hb = new QHBoxLayout;
    hb->addWidget(ok);
    hb->addWidget(cancel);
    QVBoxLayout *vb = new QVBoxLayout;
    vb->addLayout(hb1);
    vb->addLayout(hb);

    setLayout(vb);
}

newF::~newF()
{
    delete ui;
}

void newF::Ok(){
    MainArea *mainarea = new MainArea();
    mainarea->show();
}

void newF::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 40, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap));
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 230, 0);

}

QPoint newF::previousPosition() const
{
    return m_previousPosition;
}

void newF::setPreviousPosition(QPoint previousPosition)
{
    if (m_previousPosition == previousPosition)
        return;

    m_previousPosition = previousPosition;
    emit previousPositionChanged(previousPosition);
}

void newF::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
            auto dx = event->x() - m_previousPosition.x();
            auto dy = event->y() - m_previousPosition.y();
            setGeometry(x() + dx, y() + dy, width(), height());

    return QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

P.S.4. И мне бы узнать как нормально тут статью заполнять, что бы код не выглядел так ужасно(простите!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на твой третий вопрос.
Чтобы кнопка была недоступна при отсутствие текста я делаю так:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
   QString s1;
   s1 = ui->lineEdit->text();
   if(s1!="")
      ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
   else
      ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
}
```

А для того, чтобы ограничить кол-во символов или разрешить ввод только определенных символов используется inputmask.Вот ссылка на неплохой пример:
http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/widgets-lineedits.html

Comment: `void newF::TextChanged(const QString &arg1)`  @Анатолий "arg1"- у меня пишет, что он не активен, это правильно?

Comment: И посмотрите, правильный ли конект(может в нем ошибка)
`connect(name, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(TextChanged(const QString &arg1)));`

Comment: И правда простите, но я не могу до конца разобраться с маской, можете как-то меня тыкнуть носок еще глубже?

Comment: Коннект должен выглядить так:   connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(myfunction)); Где в myfunction вы можете написать тот код который я писал ранее

Comment: А вообще чтобы не заморачиваться с коннектом просто в QtCreator-е в режиме дизайнера нажмите на компонент для ввода текста и там будет пункт перейти к слоту, и выберите пункт TextChange и у вас сразу появится слот в котором писать тот код, который я давал выше, с масками завтра постараюсь найти получше вам пример(P.S.:хочу спать сейчас)

Comment: У меня все равно не работает

Comment: дай ссылку на свой вк я тебе объясню

Comment: https://vk.com/obess03 (Буду благодарен!)

Answer (score 0):

По поводу второго вопроса посмотрите в сторону [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html) ([пример](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html))